# How to make button's click handler in OpenERP 7

Tags: javascript, button, odoo

I have view configuration as shown below :

```
<record id="view_rnd_history_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">rnd.history.form</field>
    <field name="model">rnd.batch.record.history</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="History" version="7.0">
            <group>
                <field name="br_id" colspan="2"/>
                <label for="start_date" string="Date"/>
                <div>
                    <field name="start_date" class="oe_inline"/> - 
                    <field name="end_date" class="oe_inline"/>
                </div>
                <field name="batch_number" colspan="2"/>
                <field name="parameter_id" colspan="2"/>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button name="show_history" string="_Show" class="oe_highlight"/>
                or
                <button string="Close" special="cancel"/> 
            </footer>
            <div id="div_history"/>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

My question, how to make a click handler on button 'show_history'? I've try to add widget="customwidget" like this :

```
<button name="show_history" string="_Show" widget="customwidget" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

but its not working. Can someone tell me what I miss? Thank you.

Comment: It depends on what you want the program to do after You click the button. You can either: trigger python method, open new view, trigger workflow change. Take a look in here: http://bit.ly/1Dnfe6O, at the bottom there is a Button section. Its all about "type" attribute. Search through openerp core modules for statements like `"type"="object"` or `"type"="action"` and study them.

Comment: Thank @chantwaffle . I just want to call a javascript function after click the button. Using type="action" will remove those view (the view will empty). I dont't want this. If type="action" is the only solution, how to prevent the remove process? Thanks.

Comment: @Indrajaya You can define a function named has "show_history" it'll call the function and execute it. You can write code within the function about what action need to be done.